# definition and derivation of sine - unit circle - rectangle

Tags: motivation

sine is defined as:

$sin(\alpha) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$

My questions are:

- why is sine only defined on right angles?
- where does the definition comes from/is derived?
- is the unit circle used to define sine or just to show the values?

as far as I know sine is defined and derived with the idea of Similarity of Triangles
but I do not understand exactly why and why these triangles have to be right angles

Comment: Sine and cosine have nothing to do with rectangles (unless you really force it), it's all about triangles. Sine and cosine are defined using the unit circle, and you can treat their use in triangles as a special case.

Comment: Rectangles? Are you sure you don't mean right triangles?

Comment: correct, I changed that